# Laravel 5.2 : How to write this `if` sentence?

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am using Laravel 5.2,
I want to show "new"  `span`  if an article's  `updated_at`  is less 3 days,

For example:
One article's  `updated_at`  is  `2016-06-21 14:15:36` ,
now is  `2016-06-23 18:50:05` .
`2016-06-23` - `2016-06-21` =2, it is less 3,
so the "new"  `span` will be shown.
How to write the `if` sentence?

```
@if(......)  //How to write the `if` sentence here?
 <span class="label label-success">new</span>
 @endif
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Laravel uses [Carbon](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/) for it's dates, so your article's `updated_at` field is a Carbon instance. To check if the article is newer than three days, you just need to check if the `updated_at` field is newer than "now - 3 days". Luckily, Carbon understands what `-3 days` means.

```
$article->updated_at->gte(new Carbon("-3 days"))
```

Should do the job. `gte` is a method provided by Carbon and stands for "greater than or equals"

Comment: Thanks. I want to do a subtraction using `date` instead of `time` .how to do it?

Comment: Try `-3 days at midnight` instead of `-3 days`

Comment: error: `DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (-3 days at midnight) at position 8 (a): The timezone could not be found in the database` .

Comment: Oh sorry, the "at" is wrong, it's just `-3 days midnight`

Answer (score 2):

You can you use [date_diff()](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_date_date_diff.asp) function to find the days .

```
<?php
   $date1=date_create("2016-06-21");
   $date2=date_create("2016-06-23");
   $diff=date_diff($date1,$date2);
   if($diff->format("%a")<'3'){
      echo 'new span';
   }

?>
```

Comment: how to write it in the `if` sentence ?